# Etymology of "plough back" meaning to reinvest

Tags: etymology, finance

What is the etymology of the phrasal verb *plough back* which Macmillan Dictionary defines as

> [plough back](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/plough-back): to put any profits made by a business back into it in order to make it more successful
>   e.g., 
>   *All the money we raise is ploughed back into our work.*

Collins Dictionary lists the one word spelling, *ploughback*, and its American equivalent *[plowback](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plough-back)*

When and how did this expression first arise in the world of finance?

Comment: I imagine in originated in agriculture, where to `plough` a crop `back` means to turn over a growing crop and mix it in the soil, in order to improve the soil's quality

Comment: @blgt Thanks for your explanation, it's useful, I'd guessed it derives from agriculture but nowadays its chief meaning is to *reinvest profits*. I was wondering when it was first used in the field of business (no pun intended).

Comment: I've always pictured the "plow" in "plow back" as a sort of *snow plow*,  only instead of pushing huge quantities of snow before it, it's driving huge qua firs of cash wherever the driver chooses as his destination.

Comment: @DanBron that's curious. I would never have thought of that image, but it makes sense.

Comment: How about "seed money"? When you harvest something like grain (or other things, like potatoes) you need to replant some for next year's crop. I'd guess the etymology is prehistoric, certainly pre-English.

Comment: Money, effort and sweat are ploughed into the ground metaphorically, as manure might be literally ploughed in to improve the soil. Some nitrogen-fixing crops like clover may be grown specifically to be ploughed in, as they improve the soil.

Comment: Different people have different internal representations (including visualizations) of common phrases; that's where eggcorns come from, for instance. And that's only the ones that are spelled differently. False etymology is a strong force in language change.

Comment: You would particularly plough back a nitrogen-fixing crop, such as a legume, in the hope that next year's increased yield of a higher value crop would more than make up for the lost value this year.

Comment: @Mari-Lou-  Browsing I have found this : http://how360.org/english-language/208654/etymology-of-plough-back-meaning-to-reinvest

Comment: @Josh61 oh it's a copycat question. Best notify the mods. EDIT: false alarm, the two Q&A websites are "friends"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Plough*

A related phrase is to *plough money* into an investment.

The OED has *to plough into* meaning "*To embed or bury in soil, etc.; fig. to invest (money, esp. a large amount) into an enterprise or business*", their first three uses are:

> 1854   H. D. Thoreau *Walden* 8   The better part of the man is soon ploughed into the soil for compost.
>   1895   B. Sedgwick in *Westm. Gaz.* 12 Sept. 4/3   He ploughed his capital into the land, and it never came out.
>   1945   *N.Y. Times* 16 Jan. 12/1   L. P. Sharples..declared that it was important for the municipalities to plow money into airparks and small strips near the center of their communities.

*Ploughing back* is simply re-investing in a similar way that *ploughing* was investing in the first place.

Here's a *plowed money* from *[The Financial World](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=coo.31924096310697;view=1up;seq=338)* of August 29, 1921 (p.328):

[image: The receivers plowed money into the property and thereby brought the ratio down to a very low level, which may be taken as the real normal ratio, or around 34%.]

### *Plough back*

The OED has a literal use of *plough back* from 1864 ("*To plough plant material into (an area of ground) to enrich the soil; to plough in (plant material)*") from 1864 and a figurative one ("*To invest (income or profit) back* into *the enterprise producing it*") from 1912:

> 1912   *N.Y. Times* 10 July 12/3   The management did not embrace the first opportunity to increase the payment on its shares. Instead, the surplus was plowed back into the property, as railroad men say.

Comment: I was asking myself why the expression is *plough* ***back*** and not *into*. Thank you for clearing *up* the mystery.

Answer (score 3):

[Plough back](http://www.investorwords.com/10645/plough_back.html)  earnings/profits ( or US spelling is plow back):

> - to plough back profits into the company
>     to invest the profits in the business (and not pay them out as dividends to the shareholders) by using them to buy new equipment or to create new products

As noted the origin of the expression is mutated from the agriculture world, 
According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plow+back+earnings%2Cplough+back+earnings%2Cplough+back+profits%2Cplow+back+profits&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplow%20back%20earnings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplough%20back%20earnings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplough%20back%20profits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplow%20back%20profits%3B%2Cc0) the expression was used mainly from the 30s ( apparently following  the Great Depression), but its usage has decreased from the 80s/90s probably replaced by the more common 'reinvest'.

[image: Ngram chart plotting the rise and fall of "plough back"]